# How to prevent newline while formatting with Xtend

Tags: xtext

My Xtend formatter class extends AbstractFormatter2 and I would like it to format this code:

```
Board my_board {
  Pin {
    Name = my_name;
    Comment = "my_comment";
    Id= "my_id";
  }
}
```

to this one:

```
Board my_board {
  Pin {
    Name = my_name; Comment = "my_comment"; Id= "my_id";
  }
}
```

I have written the following Xtend code in a format function, but the text to be formatted remains the same.

```
val open = pin.regionFor.keyword('Name')
val close = pin.regionFor.keyword('Id')
interior(open, close)[newLines = 0]
```

What is the proper way to achieve this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
    var open = pin.regionFor.keyword('Name')
    val close = pin.regionFor.keyword("Id")
    while (open !== close) {
        open.append[
            oneSpace
        ]
        open = open.nextSemanticRegion
    }
```

or

```
var open = pin.regionFor.keyword('Name')
val close = pin.regionFor.assignment(pinAccess.myIdAssignment_12)
while (open !== close) {
    open.append[
        oneSpace
    ]
    open = open.nextSemanticRegion
}
```